# Difference between exit and quick_exit

Tags: c, c11

What are the differences between `void quick_exit( int exit_code )` which was included in c11 standard and `void exit( int exit_code )` function that already existed before c11 standard?

Comment: `quick_exit` doesn't call handlers registered with `atexit`.

Comment: I don't know enough to mark this as duplicate but have you [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758495/what-is-the-difference-between-stdquick-exit-and-stdabort-and-why-was-stdq)? How much research have you really done?

Comment: @Weather Vane ,no it wasn't so easy to find so thanks very much, it has a lot info!! ,I googled it but i didn't clearly understand when use the one function and when the other, also i wasn't searching that much for c11 standard so it didn't  happen to find the post you recommended.

Comment: I also [found this PDQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt633793.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't have any information about where these function differ ,do they have some important difference or they are pretty much the same, if they are the same why was needed to declare a new exit function??

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `quick_exit` is still unimplemented on macOS as of today (year 2023).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exit` ensures that stream buffers are flushed, closed, etc. Such behavior for `quick_exit` is not specified by the standard.

With these you can define two ways of quitting an application, one that lets you terminates with full cleaning (made by functions registered with `atexit`), and the other to let applications terminate more quickly without cleaning too much things (calls to functions registered with `at_quick_exit`).

Answer (score 5):

Only the functions _Exit, abort, signal, and `quick_exit` may be called in the signal handler from the header signal.h.

Calling any other function like, `exit`, will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

The Linux manual page for `quick_exit` is summarized as follows:

> quick_exit - exits a program quickly, running minimal cleanup
>
> The quick_exit() function exits the program quickly, calling any cleanup
>        functions registered with at_quick_exit(3), but not with atexit(3).

And for `exit`:

> exit - cause normal process termination
>
> The exit() function causes normal process termination and the value of status & 0377 is returned to the parent (see wait(2)).

So the main difference is that `quick_exit` does not perform as many cleanup operations upon exiting.