# What are some practical applications of the quick_exit and at_quick_exit functions?

Tags: c, exit

I've come across `at_quick_exit` and `quick_exit` while going over `stdlib.h` and looking for functions that I haven't implemented.

I don't understand the point of having these two functions. Do they have any practical usage?

Comment: It can be safely used in a signal handler (assuming any registered exit functions are also signal safe).

Comment: Still no clue, looks shared object related [glibc master - sourceware.org](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git&a=search&h=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster&st=grep&s=at_quick_exit)

Comment: I assume you're specifically wondering what the need for them is over the use of `at_exit` and `exit`?

Comment: @Shawn: There is no provision that `quick_exit` can be used from a signal handler.

Comment: @R.. See section 7.14.1 paragraph 5 of  C11.

Comment: @Shawn: Ah, I missed that.

Comment: @Shawn: I can't find any language restricting what the `at_quick_exit` handlers can do if `quick_exit` is called from a signal handler, which is obviously wrong... Is this an omission or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @R.. the description of `quick_exit()` says *No functions registered by the atexit function or signal handlers registered by the signal function are called.* I misspoke thinking the callbacks have the same requirements as signal handlers given that extra detail. They can't do anything to raise a signal without getting into undefined behavior though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758495/what-is-the-difference-between-stdquick-exit-and-stdabort-and-why-was-stdq/9759272#9759272

Comment: I can picture it being problematic, though - imagine a signal handler being called in the middle of a stdio function, that handler using `quick_exit()` with a callback that uses stdio functions... Anything non-reentrant could be an issue in that sort of scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically it exists in C because of C++. The relevant document from WG 14 C standard committe can be found [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1327.htm).

The document was adapted from the paper accepted by the C++ standard. The idea behind `quick_exit` is to exit the program *without* canceling all threads and *without* executing destructors of static objects. C doesn't has language support for such things as "destructors" at all and the [thread support library in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) is almost nowhere implemented. The `at_quick_exit` and `quick_exit` functions have very little to no meaning at all in C.

In C there is a function [`_Exit`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.5) that `causes normal program termination to occur and control to be returned to the host environment`, but is not required to flush open file descriptors, write unbuffered data, close open files, as opposed to [`exit()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4p4). Basically the `at_quick_exit` and `quick_exit` functions are facilities build to run custom user handles and then execute `_Exit`, while `atexit` is a facility to execute custom handlers upon calling `exit()`.

Comment: `_exit` also prevents calling `atexit` recommended following a failed return from the `exec...` family of functions preventing UB if any of the defined `atexit` functions are invalidated by the failed call.

Answer (score 0):

They essentially have no practical usage. The intent seems to be that a function that may have significant nontrivial `atexit` handlers could use `quick_exit` to exit with just a minimal subset of such handlers (that it defines by calling `at_quick_exit`) being called, under conditions where calling all the `atexit` handlers may not be safe. It may also be called from a signal handler, but it doesn't seem like there'd be anything meaningful you could do from the `at_quick_exit` handlers in that case.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `quick_exit` is not required to flush buffers, close open streams, or remove temporary files (but the system may still choose to do so) unlike `exit`.

Comment: *... or the signal handler calls any function in the standard library other than the abort function, the _Exit function, the quick_exit function, ...*