# Is using TerminateThread safe if I close the process directly afterwards anyway?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, c++20

I have a program that has multiple threads that read sensor data (with a function from a DLL) and pushes them to a buffer. The thing is, the threads are sleeping in-between with `sleep_until()` for different intervals. Can be like 5 mins and longer. Which means, if I try to close the program and wait with `join()`, I would have to wait until all threads wake up and notice that they can stop.

Would it be fine to force close them with `TerminateThread()`, because the program will exit anyway and release all resources?

I tried it and it seems to work. I am unsure if I am causing problems I am not noticing.

Comment: That's a maybe. Whole program could go belly up and not manage to flush a buffer or two on the way down or maybe not finish discharging and repositioning the deathray to that it doesn't unnecessarily kill a few minions.

Comment: What I generally do is have a really short wait that checks the time or the terminate flag to let the thread exit with just that short wait or have the threads waiting for notification messages from a timer or a terminate message so I can exit on demand more or less instantly.

Comment: One thing to worry about is, what if you Terminate a thread while it is holding a mutex?  That mutex will now be locked forever, and any other thread (including your own) that tries to lock it will hang.  You might end up with your program never exiting at all, just going non-responsive.  (And keep in mind that the locking/unlocking of mutexes isn't always obvious; any API you call might be doing that implicitly in its implementation)

Comment: Btw the elegant way to avoid having to terminate a thread is to have the thread block inside of `select()` or on a condition variable or on some other more elaborate synchronization mechanism that your main thread can signal to force the child thread to wake up ASAP.  Then when shutting down, your main thread can first signal the mechanism to cause the child thread to wake up ASAP, and then call join() to wait for the child thread to exit.  No polling or violence required.

Comment: [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758495/what-is-the-difference-between-stdquick-exit-and-stdabort-and-why-was-stdq

Comment: Why do anything? Why not just exit the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already an answer with an alternative and reference to horrors that generally are applicable to `TerminateThread` and some of the alternative suggestion.

I want to cover the specific "sits in `sleep_until`" / "the program will exit anyway" situation.

First of all, main issue with `TerminateThread` is that the thread being terminated might hold an important lock, like memory allocation lock, and sudden termination will result in eventual hang of some code executing in other threads.

The issue with "*sits in `sleep_until`*" is that the sleeper may go out of that state and do some other thing, like memory allocation, in exactly the time you call `TerminateThread`. This will be rare, maybe very rare, but still possible situation.

Making sure that the other thread is still sleeping is technically possible, but not easier than using a solution that avoids `TerminateThread`. And such a solution would still rely on an implementation detail that `sleep_until` goes directly to kernel wait, and neither C++ standard library, nor user-mode Windows API does not do allocations, etc that might be impacted by sudden `TerminateThread` in between.

---

Now regarding "*the program will exit anyway*"

Assuming you have:

```cpp
   TerminateThread(thd);
   exit(0);
```

There are still `atexit` functions and global object destructors. Which may hang if you killed a thread in unlocky moment and they do deallocation. Changing `exit` to `ExitProcess` only partly addresses that, as DLLs uninitialization is performed even on `ExitProcess`.

Safe options to kill a thread and exit could be:

```cpp
   TerminateThread(thd);
   __fastfail(0);
```

or

```cpp
   TerminateThread(thd);
   TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0);
```

The first will not execute anything except the termination instruction, the second will execute some minimum of code that is not likely to be impacted by `TerminateThread`.

But then you don't need to terminate a thread in the first place then, just call `__fastfail` or `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: Or just `return` from `main()`, which has the effect of terminating the process.

Comment: Thx that helps me. I just have one last question than. What effects can i expect from using the __fasfail(0) regarding the part there the DLL will not be uninitialization. The Process is the only one using the DLL.

Comment: @Kamui, DLL uninitialization will not be executed with `__fastfail(0)`, as well as with `TerminateProcess`. Is it harmful for you? it depends. Memory allocated by the process will be reclaimed by the OS anyway as well as other per-process resource allocation, like open file handles. Sure if there's something more, like writing some files or registry in dll uninitialization, then you shouldn't skip it.  Note that `__fastfail` is not intended for normal terminations at all, it will notify debugger and may involve Windows Error Reporting, it is basically "force crash ASAP".

Answer (score 4):

It's bad practice to terminate a thread like this. Read the Remarks section of the documentation for [`TerminateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread) and note how explicit it is about the various dangers of doing this.

Here's an excerpt from that section, at the time of writing:

> `TerminateThread` is used to cause a thread to exit. When this occurs,
> the target thread has no chance to execute any user-mode code. DLLs
> attached to the thread are not notified that the thread is
> terminating. The system frees the thread's initial stack.
>
> **Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP:**  The target thread's initial stack
> is not freed, causing a resource leak.
>
> `TerminateThread` is a dangerous function that should only be used in
> the most extreme cases. You should call `TerminateThread` only if you
> know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of
> the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time
> of the termination. For example, `TerminateThread` can result in the
> following problems:
>
> - If the target thread owns a critical section, the critical section will not be released.
> - If the target thread is allocating memory from the heap, the heap lock will not be released.
> - If the target thread is executing certain kernel32 calls when it is terminated, the kernel32 state for the thread's process could be
>   inconsistent.
> - If the target thread is manipulating the global state of a shared DLL, the state of the DLL could be destroyed, affecting other users of
>   the DLL.

That sounds horrendous! But what should you do about it?

---

A cleaner way to achieve what you want in Windows is to set up an *event*, which when signalled will cause all your threads to exit.

You create an event with [`CreateEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa) and pass that handle to all your threads. Whenever a thread wants to perform a sleep, it can use [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) (or `WaitForMultipleObjects`) with a timeout. If the timeout elapses, the function will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, so you know the application is still in the normal mode of operation and that it's also time to do your periodic task.

When it's time for the application to exit, you signal the event via [`SetEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent). This will wake up all your sleeping threads, and if the return value from the wait call is `WAIT_OBJECT_0` (or similar when waiting on multiple objects), then they know it's time to clean up and exit. They should call [`ExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitthread) when they're finished, or return cleanly from the thread procedure.

So, you would create this event once as follows:

```
// Create a manual-reset event, initially non-signalled
HANDLE hExitEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
```

Then supply it to your threads during thread creation. Typically that means you pass it via the thread argument. If you need to pass other data, just standardize that and bundle it in a struct.

Your thread loop would then look something like this:

```
// Note: assume threads have been given the handle in hExitEvent

bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hExitEvent, dwTimeoutMillseconds);

    if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        // Exit signalled: Clean up and exit thread...
        done = true;
    }
    else if (waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        // Perform your periodic task
    }
    else {
        // Handle error conditions. You might need to abort the thread.
        // Be careful about ignoring this and going straight back 
        // to waiting -- every call might fail from here, resulting
        // in this thread spinnning at 100% CPU. For safety, perhaps
        // introduce a short timeout here if you don't want to handle
        // unexpected errors.
    }
}
return 1;
```

On the main program side, after signalling exit, you would use [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) to wait on all your threads to finish. You can use a timeout here to cover yourself in abnormal conditions, and then explicitly terminate any threads that failed to exit normally.

Assuming your threads were created with [`CreateThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread), the last thing to do in your main's cleanup is to call [`CloseHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-closehandle) on all handles, even if you called `TerminateThread` on that handle.

Example shutdown procedure:

```
// Signal threads to exit
SetEvent(hExitEvent);

// Wait on all threads for a maximum of 5 seconds
DWORD waitResult = WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, threads, TRUE, 5000);

// Terminate any threads that did not exit
if (waitResult < WAIT_OBJECT_0 || waitResult >= WAIT_OBJECT_0 + numThreads)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    {
        if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(threads[i], 0))
        {
            TerminateThread(threads[i]);
        }
    }
}

// Clean up handles
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    CloseHandle(threads[i]);
}
```

Comment: I already knew that. As stated "You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination. " So my question was if it is ok to do if my thread only pushes sensor data to a buffer and sleeps. Afterwards the rest of application will be shutdown normally. Essentially the thread will be only terminated if it is waiting with this_thread::sleep_until()

Comment: @Kamui You kill a thread, you don't know in the general case what will happen. Maybe you'll have no visible signs of misbehaviour, what-so-ever. Maybe you'll be fine most of the time. Maybe you won't see the problem until after people are dead.\

Comment: @Kamui The best practice is to adhere to the operating system's API recommendations. I can't help you justify writing lazy code that goes against those recommendations -- I just don't approach software that way. When you make choices like that, you cause problems for yourself or others, either now or in the future. An interruptible sleep is a simple solution that provides well-defined control paths in your software. It allows you to trust your shutdown mechanism, and any potential ongoing development doesn't have to consider the pitfalls of calling `TerminateThread` by design.